# Using optional route parameter in sveltekit results in error

Tags: sveltekit

I want to use the optional route parameter feature sveltekit offers but it produces an error.

In my 'routes' folder I created another folder '[[lang]]' but when I want to try it out I get this error:

> Error: Invalid param: [lang. Params and matcher names can only have underscores and alphanumeric characters.

I'm pretty new to svelte and sveltekit so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `[lang]` or `[[lang]]`?

Comment: [[lang]] like in the docs: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#optional-parameters

Answer (score 1):

I just tried creating a `[[lang]]/home` route with the latest SvelteKit and it worked fine.

According to your error, the folder name seems to be detected as `[[lang]`, not `[[lang]]`.

However, when I tried renaming my `[[lang]]` folder to `[[lang]` I got a different error: `Invalid route /[[lang] — brackets are unbalanced`

To help diagnose the actual problem, I suggest creating a github repo with a simple reproduction based on the starter template from `npm create svelte@latest`